# Getting Output as FALSE in python function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

This is my function . I am passing close data to it. I am getting all FALSE value in Support Break,Resistance Break,Bull Wick,Bear Wick

```
def calculate_support_resistance_slope(close_data, left_bars=15, right_bars=15, volume_thresh=20):
    # Calculate pivots
    high_use_pivot = pd.Series(close_data).rolling(window=left_bars+right_bars+1).max().shift(-right_bars-1)
    low_use_pivot = pd.Series(close_data).rolling(window=left_bars+right_bars+1).min().shift(-right_bars-1)

    # Plot support and resistance levels
    support_resistance_levels = pd.DataFrame(index=close_data.index)
    support_resistance_levels['Support'] = low_use_pivot
    support_resistance_levels['Resistance'] = high_use_pivot

    # Calculate volume-related values
    short_volume = pd.Series(close_data).ewm(span=5, adjust=False).mean()
    long_volume = pd.Series(close_data).ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
    volume_oscillator = 100 * (short_volume - long_volume) / long_volume
    
    # Plot breaks with volume
    support_breaks = (close_data < low_use_pivot) & (close_data.shift(1) >= high_use_pivot.shift(1)) & (volume_oscillator > volume_thresh)
    resistance_breaks = (close_data > high_use_pivot) & (close_data.shift(1) <= low_use_pivot.shift(1)) & (volume_oscillator > volume_thresh)

    # Plot bull/bear wicks
    bull_wicks = (close_data > high_use_pivot) & (close_data.shift(1) <= high_use_pivot.shift(1)) & (close_data - low_use_pivot < 0)
    bear_wicks = (close_data < low_use_pivot) & (close_data.shift(1) >= low_use_pivot.shift(1)) & (high_use_pivot - close_data < 0)

    # Generate DataFrame with support/resistance breaks and wicks
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(index=close_data.index)
    result_df['Support Break'] = support_breaks
    result_df['Resistance Break'] = resistance_breaks
    result_df['Bull Wick'] = bull_wicks
    result_df['Bear Wick'] = bear_wicks

    return support_resistance_levels, result_df
```

Calling the function

```
close_data = pd.Series([10, 12, 8, 15, 10, 18, 20, 14, 25, 22])
support_resistance_levels, result_df = calculate_support_resistance_slope(close_data)
print(result_df)
```

Here the output

```
   Support Break  Resistance Break  Bull Wick  Bear Wick
0          False             False      False      False
1          False             False      False      False
2          False             False      False      False
3          False             False      False      False
4          False             False      False      False
5          False             False      False      False
6          False             False      False      False
7          False             False      False      False
8          False             False      False      False
9          False             False      False      False
```

Not getting , why I am getting all value as False

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: `low_use_pivot` is all `NaN`

Comment: You need to debug by examining / print intermediary values as the code progresses and you will see where it is going wrong.

Comment: This is not how this site works. We are not supposed to read your code debug it for you and tell you what error you have made. What we do, could be telling you why a specific pandas method doesn't work as you expected; or how you can get what you expected. But you haven't expressed any question on your code. You haven't said whether it is `.rolling` or `&` or ... that doesn't do what you expected. Apparently you understand every line of your code. So, what you are asking here is to do what you could do yourself.